# Save projected raster as a variable and not as a file Python

Tags: python-3.x, raster, gdal, coordinate-transformation, rasterio

I would like to reproject a raster and keep working on that reprojected raster instead of loading it again from a file.

To project a raster I use either `gdal`:

```
# Source
src = gdal.Open(vv_path, gdalconst.GA_ReadOnly)
src_proj = src.GetProjection()
src_geotrans = src.GetGeoTransform()

# We want a section of source that matches this:
match_ds = gdal.Open(sn2_red_path, gdalconst.GA_ReadOnly)
match_proj = match_ds.GetProjection()
match_geotrans = match_ds.GetGeoTransform()
wide = match_ds.RasterXSize
high = match_ds.RasterYSize

# Output / destination
dst_filename = os.path.join(sn1_processed_path,'vv.tif')
dst = gdal.GetDriverByName('Gtiff').Create(dst_filename, wide, high, 1, gdalconst.GDT_Float32)
dst.SetGeoTransform( match_geotrans )
dst.SetProjection( match_proj)

# Do the work
aa = gdal.ReprojectImage(src, dst, src_proj, match_proj, gdalconst.GRA_NearestNeighbour)

del dst # Flush
```

or `rasterio` from [here](https://www.earthdatascience.org/courses/use-data-open-source-python/intro-raster-data-python/raster-data-processing/reproject-raster/)

In both cases, the projected raster is saved to a file, and I have to load it again to procees it. Is it possible to save the projected raster also as a variable?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [VRT](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/vrt.html) datasets:

```
src = gdal.Open(“reference.tif”)
dst = gdal.Warp(“warped.vrt”, src, format=“vrt”, dstSRS=“EPSG:3857”)
```

This way only a small `VRT` file will be created, and you can use the `dst` dataset in downstream processing at which point the warping will be actually performed.

You can even create the `VRT` itself in memory, so nothing is written to disk at all:

```
dst = gdal.Warp(“”, src, format=“vrt”, dstSRS=“EPSG:3857”)
```

If your dataset fits entirely in memory, you can create the actual dataset in memory using the [`vsimem` virtual file system driver](https://gdal.org/user/virtual_file_systems.html), which has the upside that you have to perform the processing only once if you want to use it downstream in multiple functions:

```
dst = gdal.Warp(“/vsimem/result_inmemory.tif”, src, format=“tif”, dstSRS=“EPSG:3857”)
```

This way the processing will be performed immediately, but then you can use the dataset object to e.g. write it to disk and then perform additional processing.

Comment: Can I apply it to `gdal.ReprojectImage`? I did see the format argument there

Comment: @user88484 this should work with all `gdal` raster functions. Does `gdal.Warp` not do what you need?

Comment: `gdal.Warp` might work, but here I use `gdal.ReprojectImage` , see in my code

Comment: @user88484 yes I can see, but you can use any `gdal function that works on `gdal` datasets, using warp was just for illustration - `ReprojectImage` should work just as fine. The question was how to “save” a dataset as variable, this is how you can do it!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, the `ReprojectImage` gives `SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument` error when using `format=vrt`. Can you try the `ReprojectImage` function see if it works for you?

Comment: You need to put all keyword arguments after the positional arguments - try putting `format=vrt` at the end

Comment: No.. I get `TypeError: 'format' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`

Comment: hm this means either the format keyword is different or it’s not excepted at all

Comment: This is what they have in docs `ReprojectImage(*args, **kwargs)
ReprojectImage(Dataset src_ds, Dataset dst_ds, char const * src_wkt=None, char const * dst_wkt=None, GDALResampleAlg eResampleAlg, double WarpMemoryLimit=0.0, double maxerror=0.0, GDALProgressFunc callback=0, void * callback_data=None, char ** options=None) -> CPLErr`. You can find it here - https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#ReprojectImage. I don't see an option for `vrt`

Comment: Which means that you can't define it for this function. IMO you can do everything you need with `gdal.Warp`, possibly even easier. If you *really* want to use `ReprojectImage`, you can use my second approach using `vsimem` to create `dst` as tiff in memory (this requires your memory is big enough).